# How to add a color table to a one band tiff using GDAL?

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, colortable

I have 1-band GeoTIFF file. The color interpretation for band is gray. I want a color table in order to transform my `Col.tiff` to `Col.jpeg` or `Col.png`.

I tried putting a color table in this tiff via a .vrt:

```
gdal_translate -of VRT  Col.tiff Col.vrt
```

then adding in the .vrt:

```
<ColorInterp>Palette</ColorInterp>
<ColorTable>
   <Entry c1="0" c2="0" c3="255" c4="240"/>
   <Entry c1="0" c2="0" c3="254" c4="240"/>
   <Entry c1="0" c2="0" c3="253" c4="240"/>
   <Entry c1="0" c2="0" c3="252" c4="240"/>
</ColorTable>
```

And translate again :

```
gdal_translate Col.vrt Col.tiff
```

But it answered:

```
Warning 1: Unable to export color table to GeoTIFF file.  Color tables can only be written to 1 band or 2 bands Byte or UInt16 GeoTIFF files.
```

How can I do it?

For information, there is gdalinfo for the Band:

```
Band 1 Block=55x18 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray
  Description = Something
  Metadata:
    GRIB_COMMENT=Something[p]
    GRIB_ELEMENT=TMP
    GRIB_FORECAST_SECONDS=0 sec
    GRIB_REF_TIME=1401926400 sec UTC
    GRIB_SHORT_NAME=SMTHG
    GRIB_UNIT=[p]
    GRIB_VALID_TIME=1401926400 sec UTC
```

Comment: What max/min values does your tif have? It is Float64, so how should this decimal value correspond to the integer values for a colour palette?

Comment: Error says that output must be of type Byte or UInt16. Perhaps you should add "-ot UInt16" into the gdal_translate command.

Comment: Thanks, it works now, I just need to find the good colors :)

Comment: @AndreJoost What I've done is taking max/min values and dividing them between 255 classes. Then, for each value, I put a color.

Comment: Finally I made a Python script to make a new tiff with the same informations except there are 4bands (rgba)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

with gdal, you can color an image based on gdal_dem ([color_relief](http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html#gdaldem_color_relief))

> the syntax of the color configuration file is derived from the one
> supported by GRASS [r.colors](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.colors.html) utility. ESRI HDR color table files (.clr)
> also match that syntax. The alpha component and the support of tab and
> comma as separators are GDAL specific extensions
>
> ```
> aspect: aspect oriented grey colors
> aspectcolr: aspect oriented rainbow colors
> bcyr: blue through cyan through yellow to red
> bgyr: blue through green through yellow to red
> byg: blue through yellow to green
> byr: blue through yellow to red
> celsius: blue to red for degree Celsius temperature
> corine: EU Corine land cover colors
> curvature: for terrain curvatures (from v.surf.rst and r.slope.aspect)
> differences: differences oriented colors
> elevation: maps relative ranges of raster values to elevation color ramp
> etopo2: colors for ETOPO2 worldwide bathymetry/topography
> evi: enhanced vegetative index colors
> gdd: accumulated growing degree days
> grey: grey scale
> grey.eq: histogram-equalized grey scale
> grey.log: histogram logarithmic transformed grey scale
> grey1.0: grey scale for raster values between 0.0-1.0
> grey255: grey scale for raster values between 0-255
> gyr: green through yellow to red
> haxby: relative colors for bathymetry or topography
> ndvi: Normalized Difference Vegetation Index colors
> population: color table covering human population classification breaks
> population_dens: color table covering human population density classification breaks
> precipitation: precipitation color table (0..2000mm)
> precipitation_monthly: precipitation color table (0..1000mm)
> rainbow: rainbow color table
> ramp: color ramp
> random: random color table
> rstcurv: terrain curvature (from r.resamp.rst)
> rules: create new color table based on user-specified rules read from stdin
> ryb: red through yellow to blue
> ryg: red through yellow to green
> sepia: yellowish-brown through to white
> slope: r.slope.aspect-type slope colors for raster values 0-90
> srtm: color palette for Shuttle Radar Topography Mission elevation
> terrain: global elevation color table covering -11000 to +8850m
> wave: color wave
> ```

Rem: in you case, your gdalinfo outputs inform you that your original file is in Float, while the use of color tables requires Byte or UInt16. Therefore you could translate your file using '''gdal_translate input.tif output.tif -ot Byte''' in order to allow for unique values.

Comment: See also my extended example here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130199/changing-color-of-raster-images-based-on-their-data-values-gdal

Comment: link directly to @AndreJ's answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/132690/49134

Comment: yes, thanks, those 2015 questions should be marked as duplicate but AndreJ's answer is more detailed than mine.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able export RGB JPEG using **gdal_translate** with `[-expand {gray|rgb|rgba}]` flag. You should use command like this:

```
gdal_translate -of jpeg -expand rgb -a_nodata 255 -co worldfile=yes col.vrt col.jpg
```

There is included `-a_nodata` to leave nodata pixels white not black and `-co worldfile=yes` to include georeferencing file.
However I'm not sure about defining color table for input float data type, because definition of VRT driver states:

> ColorTable: This element is parent to a set of Entry elements defining the entries in a color table. Currently only RGBA color tables are supported with c1 being red, c2 being green, c3 being blue and c4 being alpha. The entries are ordered and will be assumed to start from color table entry 0.