# Changing color of raster images based on their data values - gdal

Tags: raster, gdal, batch, color

Let's say I have 1 band raster images with Gray Color Interpretation and I want to change their color based on their data values. Data values -1, will be Blue, -0.5 will be Light Blue, 0 will be Yellow, 0.5 will be Orange and 1 will be Red. If the data values are <-3000, I want to have that colored Black and if the data values are >3.402, that should be colored White . Will that be possible in gdal? And process that in batch?

Comment: There is an answer for that on GIS.SE: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104196/how-to-add-a-color-table-to-a-one-band-tiff-using-gdal more information about color tables here: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQRaster#Howtocreateormodifyanimagecolortable

Comment: What does c1, c2, c3, c4, ..... cN means in vrt? The easiest non-scripting way to create or modify a color palette is to translate your file to VRT (XML) format, and edit the color table in the XML file. - Does this mean that you have to modify the files one by one? What if there are many files that I need to change the color from one directory? Will these be possible also?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

c1 to c4 in the vrt file are the RGBA values you see in a 4-channel RGBA tif file. Every row corresponds to an integer palette value in the source file.

---

**EDIT**

`gdaldem` seems to be the right tool for your task:

1. Take a raster of your choice (like SRTM as an example)
2. Create the following text file named `col.txt`:

> 0 black
>
> 100 blue
>
> 200 yellow
>
> 300 orange
>
> 400 red
>
> 500 white

3. On command line, run

> gdaldem color-relief N51E007.hgt col.txt out.tif

and the result will look like this:

[image]

I have added white dashed contour lines to show that the colours get interpolated.

Instead of colour names, you can use RGB values as well, see http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html#gdaldem_color_relief for details:

```
The supported list is : white, black, red, green, blue, yellow, magenta, cyan, aqua, grey/gray, orange, brown, purple/violet and indigo
```

You can create a vrt file as output too and look into that on how the interpolating is done with `<LUT>` keys:

```
gdaldem color-relief -of VRT N51E007.hgt col.txt out.vrt

  ...
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="1">
    <ColorInterp>Red</ColorInterp>
    <ComplexSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">N51E007.hgt</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="1201" RasterYSize="1201" DataType="Int16" BlockXSize="1201" BlockYSize="1"/>
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="1201" ySize="1201"/>
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="1201" ySize="1201"/>
      <LUT>0:0,100:0,200:0,300:255,400:255,500:255</LUT>
    </ComplexSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>
```

---

**update**

To apply different transparencies, I got around with this batch:

```
gdaldem color-relief -of GTiff N51E006.hgt color.txt output6.tif -alpha 
gdaldem color-relief -of GTiff N51E007.hgt color.txt output7.tif -alpha
```

and this color.txt:

```
0. 255 255 255 0
50. 255 0 0 50
100. 0 255 0 100
150. 0 0 255 150
```

with elevation in meters, and RGBA values between 0 and 255.

Comment: what option from the gdal_calc utility will transform the data range of my source file? The source file I am using was processed using gdal_calc. I also tried to open the source file from qgis, and it has a -2.6 min and max values. I was unable to change the color then. So I thought of changing the values of the min and max, from -1 to 1. And was able to get the desired output. How will I do that?

Comment: How would you like values of -0.75, -0.25, 0.25 or 0.75 be represented? In your question it looks like you want 7 colours and nothing else. A colour ramp is also possible.

Comment: I just want to change its color based on their data values. And would want to do that in batch process. One of the color ramp available in qgis is the `RdYlBu`. That is what I preferred to use.

Comment: Is there a `light blue` color from the rdylbu color ramp?

Comment: If I'm going to add this data value and color 
`< -3000 black`
`> 3.402 white` 
to the col.txt, will this be possible/acceptable?

Comment: `aqua` should be equivalent to `light blue`. I would not use < and >, but set a minimal and maximal value.

Comment: What do you mean by `set a min and max value`? Do you mean if I set -1 as the min value anything below -1(-2, -1000, -3000, -32767 etc.) will be colored depending on what I have specified for that data value? And the same with the positive values? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Just try it out, it costs nothing ... From my example you see that everything greater than 500 will get the same colour as defined for 500.

Comment: Can I assign negative values and values with decimal places in col.txt?

Comment: If the data type allows it, yes. See http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html for allowed values. You might have to use gdal_translate if your dataset has only byte or integer type.

Comment: One of the types of color brewer palettes is diverging. And rdylbu is under that type. Can I color my raster image with that type?

Comment: I have not yet tried to use those colour ramps in pure gdal.

Comment: I tried to use the rdylbu color palette by just replacing the color name with the rgb equivalent in gdaldem and it was successful. Followed the link you gave me. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @AndreJ. Just an addition to this topic(maybe you know the answer), I want to make my output/nodata value of my output transparent but since I'm planning to overlay the output I still want the colors assigned to the image visible. Will it be possible in gdaldem? How will I do it?

Comment: From the help page http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html#gdaldem_hillshade, the option `-alpha` should add a transparency band, but I have not tested it myself.

Comment: What should be the values of the -alpha?I am using color-relief option for this.

Comment: From the same page: full opacity 255 (and no opacity for 0 value). I guess you can not mix opacity with colour names, so RGBA with four values between 0 and 255 should be best.

Comment: This is my gdaldem script `gdaldem color-relief -of GTiff input.tif -alpha color.txt output.tif`. This is my color.txt `255 255 255 0, 255 0 0 0, 0 255 0 0, 0 0 255 0` but nothing happens. No transparency were applied to the image.

Comment: See my extended answer.

Comment: Where can I find the elevation value of the raster? The value that corresponds to the assigned color, is that the elevation value? I forgot to include the assigned value for every color. Sorry. This is the content, `-1 255 255 255 0, -0.5 255 0 0 0, 0 0 255 0 0, 0.5 0 0 255 0,1 0 0 0 0`

Comment: Yes, it is the first value. If you set all transparency to zero, you won't see anything.

Comment: But in my case, only the nv is my problem; `nv 255 255 255 0`. The output still appeared white. It didn't became transparent :(

Comment: what value is used for NODATA in your input file? `nv` will not work.

Comment: `gdaldem color-relief` seems to create **multiband** rather than a **singleband**

Answer (score 5):

Here is a auto color script based on AndreJ's code:

```
================================================================================
Usage:
-------------
Custom color:
python gdaldem.py input_tif.tif color.txt output_color.tif
Auto color:
python gdaldem.py input_tif.tif auto output_color.tif

"""
import subprocess
import sys
import os
import tempfile
import numpy as np


def main(input_file, color_file, output_file):
    cmd = "gdaldem color-relief " + input_file \
          + ' ' + color_file + ' ' + output_file
    subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)


def gen_color_file(input_file):
    fp, temp_file = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='.txt')

    dem = DEM(input_file)
    dem.open()
    phase_data = dem.height_band.ReadAsArray()

    max_ph = np.nanmax(phase_data)
    min_ph = np.nanmin(phase_data)
    range_ph = max_ph-min_ph
    colors = ['black', 'blue', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red', 'white']
    with open(temp_file, 'w') as f:
        for i, c in enumerate(colors[:-1]):
            f.write(str(int(min_ph + (i + 1)*range_ph/len(colors))) +
                    ' ' + c + '\n')
        f.write(str(int(max_ph - range_ph/len(colors))) +
                ' ' + colors[-1] + '\n')
    os.close(fp)
    return temp_file


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_file = sys.argv[1]
    color_file = sys.argv[2]
    output_file = sys.argv[3]
    if color_file == 'auto':
        print '\nauto generating color file'
        color_file = gen_color_file(input_file)
    with open(color_file, 'r') as f:
        print '\ncolor file contents'
        print '='*50
        for l in f.readlines():
            print l
    print '='*50
    main(input_file, color_file, output_file)
```