# python install rio-color could not load plugin rio -color

Tags: python, python-2.7, rasterio, rio

hello I have install python  rio plugin to add color ramp in some DEM datasets.
I have install using download from [GitHub](https://github.com/mapbox/rio-color) .

but if I run rio --help in cmd then :

```
C:\Windows\System32>rio --help
Usage: rio [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  Rasterio command line interface.

Options:
  -v, --verbose       Increase verbosity.
  -q, --quiet         Decrease verbosity.
  --aws-profile TEXT  Selects a profile from your shared AWS credentials file
  --version           Show the version and exit.
  --gdal-version
  --help              Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  atmos      † Warning: could not load plugin. See `rio.exe atmos --help`.
  blocks     Write dataset blocks as GeoJSON features.
  bounds     Write bounding boxes to stdout as GeoJSON.
  calc       Raster data calculator.
  clip       Clip a raster to given bounds.
  color      † Warning: could not load plugin. See `rio.exe color --help`.
  convert    Copy and convert raster dataset.
  edit-info  Edit dataset metadata.
  env        Print information about the Rasterio environment.
  gcps       Print ground control points as GeoJSON.
  info       Print information about a data file.
  insp       Open a data file and start an interpreter.
  mask       Mask in raster using features.
  merge      Merge a stack of raster datasets.
  overview   Construct overviews in an existing dataset.
  rasterize  Rasterize features.
  sample     Sample a dataset.
  shapes     Write shapes extracted from bands or masks.
  stack      Stack a number of bands into a multiband dataset.
  transform  Transform coordinates.
  warp       Warp a raster dataset.
```

but in atmos and in color I take this message :

```
atmos      † Warning: could not load plugin. See `rio.exe atmos --help`.
color      † Warning: could not load plugin. See `rio.exe color --help`.
```

I need more setting or more install package to work ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, and this isn't a complete answer.  One note is that `rio-color` is for color balancing and normalizing optical imagery collected in the visible wavelengths and does not have any machinery for generating and applying color ramps to DEMs.  If you need help doing that it looks like this question is a good place to start:

[Changing color of raster images based on their data values - gdal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130199/changing-color-of-raster-images-based-on-their-data-values-gdal)

That said, your error messages indicate an exception is being raised when the `atmos` and `color` plugins are loaded.  Could you try executing both:

```
$ rio atmos --help
$ rio color --help
```

and pasting the output?  A few more questions:

1. What version of Rasterio (`$ rio --version`)?
2. How did you install Rasterio?
3. How did you install `rio-color`?  You mention downloading from GitHub, but what commands did you execute after that?