# How to implement a temperature map using leaflet/openlayers?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, openlayers, heat-map

I am new on Leaflet/OpenLayers. I have been searching the internet for a way to create a temperature map like the one below, but I didn't succeed...the only thing I made was a classical heatmap, but not even closer to this example.

This is the scenario:

- I have 5100 coordenates (longitude, latitude, metric)
- This metric varies from 0 to 1

I want to implement a temperature map like the one below(from openlayers 3 cookbook):

[image]

I'm not looking for a 'ready to go' tool or a straightforward answer, I just want a 'direction'.

What I have implemented so far looks like this(completely different from the one above):

[image]

Comment: Is your data irregularly spaced? If it is, then you need to interpolate it to a grid using one of many techniques - inverse distance weighting, kriging etc.

Comment: @Spacedman Yes, it's completely irregularly spaced. I do neet to interpole it, but how I get the temperature effect like in the first map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will argue that this is not a job to be done in a web browser, but rather on the backend. I am not aware of any library or plugin that performs the necessary transformations in a web browser.

You need to perform [gridding](https://www.gdal.org/grid_tutorial.html) on your data, in order to convert your vector (point) dataset into a raster dataset. For this, [`gdal_grid`](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html) does the job (although you can use other GIS tools for this).

After that you'll have a raster file with values ranging from 0 to 1 for each cell (read "for each pixel"; this is since your original data values range from 0 to 1). You'll probably want to convert that raster image into a 3-channel RGB raster image. For this, [`gdaldem`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130199/changing-color-of-raster-images-based-on-their-data-values-gdal/132690#132690) does the job (once again, you can use other GIS tools).

Lastly, if your goal is to display this in Leaflet/OpenLayers, then you'll need to slice the raster image into tiles to achieve some performance. See [`gdal2tiles`](https://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html) and similar tools.

Comment: Thanks @IvanSanchez! Seems that your approach is exactly what I was looking for. I will try it today.

Comment: i found this extremely helpful.