# Add color table to NDVI using GDAL

Tags: qgis, gdal, ndvi, sentinel-2, gdal-translate

I have an `NDVI` tif file that was generated from `Sentinel 2A` data using the `gdal_calc` method. I now want to add a red-green colour table to this file so that it matches the image below. I have managed to do this using `QGIS` and now want to replicate it using `gdal`.

I tried adding the `--color-table=<file path.txt>` parameter to the `gdal_calc` command, but this returned an error: `ERROR 6: ndvi.tif, band 1: SetColorTable() only supported for Byte or UInt16 bands in TIFF format.` My original command to create the `ndvi` is:

```
docker run --rm -v /Users:/Users osgeo/gdal:alpine-normal-latest gdal_calc.py --calc="((B.astype(float)-A.astype(float))/(B.astype(float)+A.astype(float)))" -A /Users/hyprstack/gdal-test/SAMPLE-DATA/GRANULE/L1C_T30UXD_A031022_20210531T111450/IMG_DATA/T30UXD_20210531T110621_B04.jp2 -B /Users/hyprstack/gdal-test/SAMPLE-DATA/GRANULE/L1C_T30UXD_A031022_20210531T111450/IMG_DATA/T30UXD_20210531T110621_B08.jp2 --outfile=/Users/hyprstack/gdal-test/ndvi.tif --type=Float32 --color-table=/Users/hyprstack/gdal-test/color_map.txt --overwrite
```

Output of the NDVI:

[image]

Desired output with color:

[image]

This is the exported colour table file from `QGIS`:

```
# QGIS Generated Color Map Export File
INTERPOLATION:INTERPOLATED
-1,215,25,28,255,-1.0000
-0.5,253,174,97,255,-0.5000
0,255,255,192,255,0.0000
0.5,166,217,106,255,0.5000
1,26,150,65,255,1.0000
```

How can I achieve this with `gdal`?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130199/changing-color-of-raster-images-based-on-their-data-values-gdal) too!

However I had to correct my colour table file to:

```
# QGIS Generated Color Map Export File
-1,215,25,28,255,-1.0000
-0.5,253,174,97,255,-0.5000
0,255,255,192,255,0.0000
0.5,166,217,106,255,0.5000
1,26,150,65,255,1.0000
```

And then ran the command:

`docker run --rm -v /Users:/Users osgeo/gdal:alpine-normal-latest gdaldem color-relief /Users/hyprstack/gdal-test/ndvi.tif /Users/hyprstack/gdal-test/color_map.txt /Users/hyprstack/gdal-test/ndvi_color.tif`