# How to apply a color to a geotiff image based on the elevation data?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, c++

I want to apply a color to an geotiff image (which contains only elevation and coordinates info) based on the elevation data . How to do that using GDAL in c++.? Is there any example related to this?

Comment: Have you checked the [GDAL documentation](http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html) or [tutorials](https://github.com/clhenrick/gdal_hillshade_tutorial)?

Comment: Perhaps at least partly duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104196/how-to-add-a-color-table-to-a-one-band-tiff-using-gdal

Answer (score 2):

gdaldem (color-relief) helps me to apply color for geotiff image based on height value.

Eg:  ***gdaldem color-relief <"input"> <"color_relief_text_file"> <"output">***

color_relief_text_file => text file (should contain elevation data , R value,G vale,B value)
       e.g 
           0 255 255 255
           130 250 120 20
           150 10 25 60

For more information about gdaldem (color-relief):
http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html#gdaldem_color_relief

GDALDEMProcessing() is corresponding C++ API function

About GDALDEMProcessing(): 
http://www.gdal.org/gdal__utils_8h.html#a5d8486d2fd4a7a39bc954eb7f4410053

Comment: Hi SUD, Hi Friends, can anybody give an example of the color_relief_text_file in more detail? Should it be single line or multiple line? Thanks

Comment: Hi Santosa.. I hope this link will help you http://tilemill-project.github.io/tilemill/docs/guides/terrain-data/

I used multiple line color_relief_text_file. I haven't used single line file.
But the order is elevation data, R value,G Value & B Value

Comment: It should be Multiple line file

Answer (score 1):

This C++ repository (https://github.com/khafen74/raster2png) was developed to convert GeoTiffs to colored PNG images using GDAL.

You can create a GDAL color table like so:

```
colorTable = new GDALColorTable(GPI_RGB);
```

Then create color entries and make a color ramp.

```
nTansparency = 0;
GDALColorEntry blk, wht;
blk.c1 = 0, blk.c2 = 0, blk.c3 = 0, blk.c4 = nTransparency;
wht.c1 = 255, wht.c2 = 255, wht.c3 = 255, wht.c4 = nTransparency;

colorTable->CreateColorRamp(1, &blk, 255, &wht);
```

This file contains code to create a color ramp and apply it to a raster band. (https://github.com/khafen74/raster2png/blob/master/renderer.cpp).