# How to change the color intepretation field of a GeoTIFF file using GDAL?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have the following problem, I have a GeoTIFF file that is for now color interpreted as gray. When using `gdalinfo` I have the following results

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: out.tif
Size is 6957, 13662
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["unknown",
        SPHEROID["WGS84",6378137,298.257223563]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]
Origin = (92.138443059661412,28.568318690426047)
Pixel Size = (0.001364919790129,-0.001364919790129)
Metadata:
    AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
 INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  92.1384431,  28.5683187) ( 92d 8'18.40"E, 28d34' 5.95"N)
Lower Left  (  92.1384431,   9.9207845) ( 92d 8'18.40"E,  9d55'14.82"N)
Upper Right ( 101.6341900,  28.5683187) (101d38' 3.08"E, 28d34' 5.95"N)
Lower Right ( 101.6341900,   9.9207845) (101d38' 3.08"E,  9d55'14.82"N)
Center      (  96.8863165,  19.2445516) ( 96d53'10.74"E, 19d14'40.39"N)
Band 1 Block=6957x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-9999
```

As you can see the `colorInterp` is shown as gray. So is there a way to have change this to green for example. The goal of this procedure would be then to use `gdal2tiles.py` to have a web representation of my GeoTIFF but I want it in another color than in a grayscale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a band color interpretation to "green" is meant for the RGB compositing (displaying three band of a multiband raster in the three primary color to obtain a full color image, and chosing which one of the three band will correspond to green). You could do it on a multiband raster using gdal_edit.py, but it would not be the right thing to do. In your case, what you need is more like a color map because you have only one band, but you want to display it with graduated colors.

This can be done with gdaldem,  you can have a look at those answers : [How to add a color table to a one band tiff using GDAL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104196/how-to-add-a-color-table-to-a-one-band-tiff-using-gdal) and [Changing color of raster images based on their data values - gdal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130199/changing-color-of-raster-images-based-on-their-data-values-gdal/132690#132690)