# Adding color table with Python and GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, colortable

I am trying to embed a color table into a raster using Python and GDAL without success.  I was trying to follow the example [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325615/store-geotiff-with-color-table-python)

```
colors = gdal.ColorTable()
with open(color, 'r') as f:
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    temp = tuple(line.split(" ")[:4])
    tempi = [eval(i) for i in temp]
    send = tempi[0], tuple(tempi[1:4])
    print(send)
    colors.SetColorEntry(send)
```

this is this first item sent to colors.SetColorEntry (from a call to print)

(1, (115, 92, 64))

and traceback shows the error

```
TypeError: ColorTable_SetColorEntry expected 3 arguments, got 2
```

Can anyone shed some light on this and send me in the right direction?  What other argument is it wanting?

Comment: Thanks @PKG, problems solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is due to Python way of taking function arguments. You can modify your last line as below and check. The rest can remain the same.

`colors.SetColorEntry(*send)`

`send` is a tuple. The function `SetColorEntry` expects 2 arguments, (1) the pixel value, and (2) the RGB color as a tuple. You are generating all the data correctly, but instead of passing the required values to the function as it expects, you are "packing" it to another variable/tuple (`send`). The `*` symbol before the tuple, "unpacks" the values and passes to the function.