# Color table legend for GeoTIFF

Tags: raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, colortable

I have a single-band GeoTIFF whose entries are all integers. I'm creating this GeoTIFF using GDAL.

I would like to associate those integers with strings indicating what the integers mean so that the interpretation of the data can ride along with the data in a systematized way.

This is kind of like a [color table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325615/store-geotiff-with-color-table-python).

Does GeoTIFF offer any mechanism for this? I'll be using this with GDAL and QGIS, but can do custom coding to make things work.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add and show a Raster Attribute Table (RAT). There is a plugin https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/RasterAttributeTable/ for that. There are some videos about how to use the plugin, for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=No9I3PHofss.