# gdal_rasterize using color from feature property

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-rasterize

Each feature in my geojson file contains a property with hex color codes. Is it possible to convert these vector feature-collection to a geotiff using this color code on every feature ? I populate the properties myself, so I could add any property I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that gdal_rasterize can do is documented in https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html. Without changing the code the best you can to is to burn a coded value for the colors with `-a` "

> -a <attribute_name> Identifies an attribute field on the features to be used for a burn-in value. The value will be burned into all output
> bands.

I suggest to create a single band 8-bit image with values 1,2,3,4....
Once you have the image it should be possible to color it by creating a vrt file and adding a color palette into it as in this question [How to add a color table to a one band tiff using GDAL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104196/how-to-add-a-color-table-to-a-one-band-tiff-using-gdal). It did not work in the question for 64-bit data but with 8-bit data it should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried @user30184 suggestion, still not sure if I'm doing this right.

So I have 2 Features in my geojson-file with the property "color_prop". One feature has value 1, the other value 2.

1: Creating the getiff from geojson, single band, Byte

```
gdal_rasterize -l TestLayer -a color_prop -tr 0.1 0.1 -a_nodata 0.0 -te 856360.2911711 6863101.66193259 856687.30377687 6863290.112259374 -ot Byte -of GTiff INPUT.geojson OUTPUT.tif
```

2: Create test VRT File

```
<ColorInterp>Palette</ColorInterp>
<ColorTable>
   <Entry c1="255" c2="0" c3="0" c4="255"/>
   <Entry c1="0" c2="255" c3="0" c4="255"/>
</ColorTable>
```

3: Translate to VRT Format

```
gdal_translate -of VRT  OUTPUT.tiff test.vrt
```

4: Translate again:

```
gdal_translate test.vrt OUTPUT_2.tiff
```

So the feature with property value 1 should be red, the other should be green, right? I can see only one feature in QGIS, and it's black. What I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Sorry for my stupidity, the other polygon was just white, and my background was also white... works now:

1: Convert geojson to geotif with gdal_rasterize

2: Create VRT from the generated tif

```
gdal_translate -f vrt OUTPUT.tif generated.vrt
```

3: Edit VRT, add ColorTable

4: Translate back to new tif

```
gdal_translate test.vrt OUTPUT_2.tiff
```