# How to pass options in Python GDAL binding?

Tags: python, gdal, gdaldem

I am trying to color a GeoTIFF file and convert it to PNG. Several thread ([1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130199/changing-color-of-raster-images-based-on-their-data-values-gdal), [2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104196/how-to-add-a-color-table-to-a-one-band-tiff-using-gdal)) have pointed the [gdaldem](https://gdal.org/programs/gdaldem.html) function. Here I am now porting the function to Python. Using the documentation, I can pass [DEMProcessingOptions](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.DEMProcessingOptions) to [DEMProcessing](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.DEMProcessing).

How do I pass the DEMProcessingOptions object to DEMProcessing correctly? I have this on my code:

```
from osgeo import gdal

src_ds = gdal.Open('./example.tif')
options = gdal.DEMProcessingOptions(colorFilename='./color_ramp.txt', format='PNG')
ds = gdal.DEMProcessing('./example_converted.png', src_ds, processing='color-relief', options)
```

I get the error:

> Cell In [7], line 3
> ds = gdal.DEMProcessing('./example_converted.png', src_ds, processing='color-relief', options)
> ^ SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

If I remove the variable names in the function:

```
ds = gdal.DEMProcessing('./example_converted.png', src_ds, 'color-relief', options)
```

It would error:

> TypeError: DEMProcessing() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were
> given

Comment: the error says to pass the keyword to a positional argument, try pass something like options=options

Comment: Thank you @MarcoReliquias.

Comment: it works? if works tell me to write a answer to you flag as correct

Comment: Yes, it worked @MarcoReliquias.

Comment: please flag as correted answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error thrown, indicates that you need to name the parameters with the correct keywords.
try passing the options with this keyword:

```
from osgeo import gdal

src_ds = gdal.Open('./example.tif')
options = gdal.DEMProcessingOptions(colorFilename='./color_ramp.txt', format='PNG')
ds = gdal.DEMProcessing('./example_converted.png', src_ds, processing='color-relief', options=options)
```